# Open hidden elements one at a time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, javascript-objects, nodelist

please I am trying to create a FAQ like functionality, I have some elements hidden so when I click on a button it opens and hides it. I have been able to do this but I am not getting what I actually want. I might have done something wrong I suppose. So, there are 5 elements with the same className, this will help me target them all and run a for loop to kind of break them apart. However if I click on this button to open one of the element the other ones open.

```js
const openBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".openBtn")
const openContent = document.querySelectorAll(".openContent")

for(btn of openBtn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for(content of openContent) {
            if (content.classList.contains('hidden')) {
                content.classList.remove('hidden');
                content.classList.add('flex')
            } else {
                content.classList.remove('flex');
                content.classList.add('hidden')
            }
        }
    })
}
```

[image: So as you can see, If I click on the chevron icon for just one of the wither About Us, Careers or just any of the 5 every other one opens. How do I fix this ?]

So as you can see, If I click on the chevron icon for just one of the wither About Us, Careers or just any of the 5 every other one opens. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Yes, because you loop through `.openContent` elements and toggle it all, can you please add some HTML markups?

Comment: If I do the code will be too much because I am working with Tailwind in it. What would you have me do. Let me try if it'd work

Comment: What I can advise you is to find the corresponding section on each accordion and toggle it only instead of toggling all sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't going to post even the most general version of your HTML, here is a general outline.

First, each button gets a data attribute for target,then each FAQ div gets an ID attribute that matches the data target attribute.

I attach the click handler to the document and look for openBTN on the clicked element. Then I loop through every OPENED div to close it. Then I get the target data attribute and add the appropriate classes.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.toString().includes("openBtn")) {

    let opened = document.querySelectorAll(".openContent.flex");

    opened.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.add("hidden");
      el.classList.remove("flex");
    });
    let target = document.querySelector(e.target.dataset.target)
    target.classList.remove("hidden");
    target.classList.add("flex");
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button data-target="#faq1" class="openBtn">OPEN</button>
<div id="faq1" class="openContent hidden">1</div>

<button data-target="#faq2" class="openBtn">OPEN</button>
<div id="faq2" class="openContent hidden">2</div>

<button data-target="#faq3" class="openBtn">OPEN</button>
<div id="faq3" class="openContent hidden">3</div>

<button data-target="#faq4" class="openBtn">OPEN</button>
<div id="faq4" class="openContent hidden">4</div>
```